# How can I create a description label in the CCK  form?

Tags: entities

I have a form with CCK.  I have the fields into fieldsets.  I need to add a text.

```
Fieldset a
   field1
   field2
fieldset b
   field3
   field4
   field5
   Here is the text (is not field)
```

How can I add a text in the "fieldset b", below the "field 5" and before the save button?

Thanks.